# Infinite for loop

Tags: java, for-loop, while-loop, infinite-loop

This code works fine:

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        long endTime = startTime + 60000;
        long index = 0;

        while (true) {
            double x = Math.sqrt(index);
            long now = System.currentTimeMillis();
            if (now > endTime) {
                break;
            }

            index++;
        }
        System.out.println(index + " loops in one minute.");
    }
}
```

But then, I tried rewriting it into a `for loop`, and it gets stuck in an infinite loop.

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        long endTime = startTime + 60000;

        int i = 0;
        for (long now = 0; now < endTime; i++) {
            Math.sqrt(i);
            now = System.currentTimeMillis();
            System.out.println("now" + now);
            System.out.println("end" + endTime);
        }
    }

    System.out.println(i+"calculations done in one minute");
}
```

Comment: You are resetting the value of `now` inside your loop. So, `now` will always be less than `endTime`.

Comment: How is your second method approach compiling?  That `System.out` is outside of any method.

Comment: It's not an infinite loop, just wait 1 minute.

Comment: @Jbird: `now` is set to `System.currentTimeMillis()`, which is why it should work.

Comment: What is the output?  There should be reams and reams of it.  Maybe writing the output is what's making it take longer than a minute?

Comment: Note that the compiler can tell that `Math.sqrt(i)` isn't doing anything and may be optimizing it out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your second example is not an infinite loop, just wait 1 minute.

```
long endTime = startTime + 60000;
```

set the endTime to 60000 milliseconds in the future, that means 60 seconds, means 1 minute.

The standard output is just printing extremely fast.

Put a `Thread.sleep(1000L)` in the loop and you will see 61 statements being printed before it ends.

```
long endTime = 1378140843604L; // for example
for (long now = 0; now < endTime; i++) {
    now = System.currentTimeMillis(); // will be 1378140783604, 1378140784604, 1378140785604 and so on
    System.out.println("now" + now); 
    System.out.println("end" + endTime);
    Thread.sleep(1000L);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
public class Main {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    long endTime = startTime + 60000;

    int i = 0;
    for (long now = 0; now < endTime; i++) {
        Math.sqrt(i);
        now = System.currentTimeMillis();
        System.out.println("now" + now);
        System.out.println("end" + endTime);
    }

    System.out.println(i+"calculations done in one minute");
}
}
```

The only difference between mine an yours is where I put this: (yours is outside the main method)

```
System.out.println(i+"calculations done in one minute");
```

You should also be aware it take just microseconds to run through the loop so you're getting a huge output.